# Can the user save an incomplete form in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have built a long (14-page) grant application, and when I was testing it I stopped in the middle and (long story) refreshed the page. All the sample data I had entered was lost.

This grant application requires the upload of various financial and support information, so the process is going to take the applicant a lot of time. What provisions are there in Cognito Forms for an applicant to save an incomplete form and return to it later?

Answer (score 1):

You can now enable [Save & Resume](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/save-resume) on your [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), which allows users to easily save their work in progress and return at a later time to complete and submit their form.

[image]

Comment: I'm a _little_ slow in responding (I didn't get a notification email!) but thanks for this. We initially went with another online forms provider in order to have the Save & Resume feature, but have since switched to Cognito Forms and are very satisfied with your service. So, again, thanks for listening to your customers.

Comment: Wonderful!  Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do not currently support the ability to save and resume a form. This is something that we are actively looking into and plan to release in the future. You can follow our progress on this feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/Bk6swilY).